# Random mailing via data-based subscription SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscription, mailing

I have a report created using ssrs. The report displays information about customer debt. Using multiple selection, you can generate a report for several clients (one sheet = one client). This information must be sent to consumers by email once a month. A data-based subscription was created for this purpose. The input parameter to the report is the client ID. The list of emails was created in SQL and transferred to the report through a procedure
But we were faced with a situation that one client could receive documents of other consumers in addition to his own document (there is no pattern in how and when this occurs, random mailing in different months).
There are absolutely no ideas in which direction to move. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

We checked the procedure responsible for generating the report, the email corresponds to the client, it’s probably an issue with SSRS

Let me add: yesterday I sent documents from 4 clients to my email. One of them arrived incorrectly (For John, one attachment with two pages was generated - one document for him, the other for Julia). Probably the issue is not in the SSRS subscription, but in the sub-report.
Report structure: Main report, which is responsible for mailing and sub-report, which is responsible for generating a stack of documents for clients. I checked all the parameters - everything is correct

Comment: *"Has anyone encountered a similar problem?"* If the answer was "yes" how would that help you here?

Comment: I personally wouldn't be using SSRS to send emails directly to customers. I would have my own service which I am fully in control of.

Comment: I thought SSRS kept a history of the reports generated?

Comment: I've been using SSRS data driven subscription for years and have never had this issue. I can almost guarantee you that it's a report design issue or an issue with your subscription dataset. Without looking at either, there is no way we can help you with this issue